Very interesting Gibonacci covering problem for the set of integers $1$ to $n$
I am doing my math essay in University and is in the process of choosing what to write and research.
As we were learning about Fibonacci, Lucas, Gibonacci sequences (generalised scenario where $G_{n}=G_{n-1}+G_{n-2}$ and starting with two numbers $G_1$ and $G_2$), I have an idea.
(For some background information, for Fibonacci, it's $G_1=1$ and $G_2=2$, and for Lucas it's $G_1=2$ and $G_2=1$.
For example, a Gibonacci sequence starting with $1$ and $3$ will be like $1,3,4,7,11...$)
The idea is called: What is the least number of Gibonacci sequences (with different starting $G_1$ and $G_2$) that must be used to 'cover' an integer set containing integers $1$ to $n$?
For example, like for $1$ to $10$, we first try to cover it with the Fibonacci, $1,2,3,5,8$, and we have $4,7,9,10$ left. So we try to cover it up with some other Gibonacci sequence, like say for $G_1=1$ and $G_2=3$, and we cover $1,3,4,7$, but we still have $9$ and $10$ left, and we find more Gibonacci sequences to cover those.
What do you think of this as an essay topic? Are there any ideas to crack this problem?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In my opinion, this is an interesting and fun problem. You could definitely make some progress, see below for what I'd consider reasonable or unreasonable to achieve.

You ask for ideas to tackle this question, so let me outline the usual ways to approach this type of problem. I won't give any proofs to not spoil your research. Let $a_n$ be the smallest number of Gibonacci sequences necessary to cover all the natural numbers up to $n$.

Try to find algorithms that produce such coverings, prove that they are correct and determine or estimate how many sequences they need. This gives you an upper bound for $a_n$. In the comments you can already find one easy example for such an algorithm, however counting the sequences it uses might be hard. You can also try finding upper bounds non-constructively, via general abstract arguments. This is usually much harder, because there is no obvious starting point.
On the other side, you should try finding lower bounds for $a_n$. This is usually more difficult, since it is, by its nature, non-constructive: You can't just find an example, you have to prove none can exist. Again you can find a starting point in the comments.

In both cases, it can sometimes be useful to only consider large $n$, though I'm not sure if that helps much here. Ideally, if you do both of these long enough, your upper and lower bounds converge, so that you can describe the exact behaviour of $a_n$ (at least in the limit). But that is often not reasonable to expect.

You should experiment and collect data. This is probably where you should start. You can begin by hand, but to get enough results, you'll have to use a computer. Computing the value of $a_n$ is not easy, even for relatively small numbers. The code I quickly thew together to get a feel for the problem only managed $n\leq 17$ before its runtime exceeded my patience. Optimizing this to compute exact values can be an interesting challenge in itself. But equally important: Implement the algorithms you found in the first bullet point to understand their growth. Use this data to form conjectures that you then can try to prove.


Doing the above, you should definitely be able to get good upper and lower bounds on $\frac{a_n}n$ (note that the bounds from the comments can be significantly improved), and conjecture better ones backed by the data you computed. Just to get you some ideas: I proved $\frac15\leq \frac{a_n}n\leq\frac13$, and the best algorithm I found seems to need about $0.26n$ covers, for $n\leq 10^5$. Apart from improving these constants, it might be difficult to say any more, at least I don't see any easy way forward. But just as an inspiration, here are some other questions you could consider. I didn't spend much time thinking about these, so I can't judge how hard they are:

For each $n$, how many different optimal coverings exist?
Can you rephrase your problem so that some well-known optimization theory can be applied? For example, can you model it as a linear or convex program? Can analytical methods be useful?
Is there a fast algorithm that finds very good, but not necessarily optimal coverings, say one that uses $a_n(1+\varepsilon)$ sequences for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$?
What if you replace the recurrence relation $g_n=g_{n-1}+g_{n-2}$ by some other linear recurrence relation $g_n=ag_{n-1}+bg_{n-2}$? Are your methods still applicable? Do you get similar or fundamentally different results?


In the comments you express the hope to publish in a research journal. Let me be completely honest here: The chances of that happening are astronomically small, with any topic you could choose. You'd have to have some genius idea that results in a proof of something broadly applicable and interesting to mathematicians, but you lack their experience and training. But don't let that discourage you: Everyone starts small, and producing something you can be proud of should be enough motivation. Good luck!

I can't say anything big, as I am merely an amateur. But have you read about sieve method?
In sieving, there is first of all the set of natural numbers from 1 to X,
and then a set of primes whose multiples  are to be taken out of the naturals.
This at least might give you some idea of what factors you may have to consider.
For instance, as you vary the initial values, you may use same numbers in covering.
Or you may only count the number of elements covered by Gibonacci.
But I think that a success in this line of argument may be almost a miracle.
In the least, getting to know sieve method will be good for you.
I hope this helps.
